# URL Image only shows when browser resized

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using `React.js` and `firebase`. I am fetching an image from firebase and trying to render it in a component.

When the image URL is available, I `setState` the `URL`, but the image still does not show.

```
componentDidMount(){
const that = this;
    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref("hero1.png")
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(url => {
        console.log(url);
        that.setState({url})
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle any errors
      });
}
```

// rendering the image

```
...
{ this.state.url &&
                this.state.slides.map((slide, index) => {
                  console.log(slide.imageUrl);   // url is being printed here
                  return (
                    <div
                      key={index}
                      onDragStart={this.handleOnDragStart}
                      className="slider-wrapper"
                    >
                      <div key={index} className="slider-content">
                          <img src={this.state.url} />   // when I set a hard-coded url, it works, but 
                                                         //does not work in state
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
...
```

One more thing, when I resize the browser, the image shows up immediately. Don't know why

Comment: Use index as key is not preferred, you may try to use index + URL instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I removed key from the child div and updated the other key to slide.imageUrl:

```
{ this.state.url &&
                this.state.slides.map((slide, index) => {
                  console.log(slide.imageUrl);   // url is being printed here
                  return (
                    <div
                      key={slide.imageUrl}
                      onDragStart={this.handleOnDragStart}
                      className="slider-wrapper"
                    >
                      <div className="slider-content">
                          <img src={this.state.url} />   // when I set a hard-coded url, it works, but 
                                                         //does not work in state
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
```

Comment: I have another version. Try this one.

Comment: No success. I think the issue is somehow with the img src not being updated. because the url is being displayed in the console

Comment: I have another idea, based on keikai's comment

Comment: I have no more idea. Your error suggests that re-rendering do not occur after url change. But component should re-render if its state changed. That's what I try to solve in the first iteration.

Comment: you are right but it was due to the library (posted an answer). Thanks for your help bro.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a library (`react-alice-carousel`) to render the slides of images. This was causing problem. Just switched the library to react-animated-slider, and it worked.
Thanks, everybody for helping me and for your time.